# in c how actual linking take place for function defined in other file

Tags: c

i have two files

main.c:

```
int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

and second file

func.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func()
{
    printf("welcome");
}
```

I want to know that how call to function (func) is resolved by linker. I know that relocation happens with the help of relocation table but i cant understand how exactly this happens

Comment: Too broad, so voting to close this.. Read documentation on how linking works and if you have a more specific question, do come back. [\[ Here \]](http://edn.embarcadero.com/kr/article/29930) is a good resource for you to start with.

Comment: each file is a separate compilation unit and will be compiled to separate *.o files. Linking will read the global symbol on those *.o files

Answer (score 1):

That's what declarations are for. Consider the following code:

```
extern void func(void);

int main(void)
{
     func(void);
     return 0;
}
```

when compiled with i.e. `gcc -c main.c`, it will produce a `main.o` object file, where the main function will look like this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <main+0x9>
   9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   f:   c3                      retq
```

And the relocation table will contain an entry:

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000005 R_X86_64_PC32     func-0x0000000000000004
```

Now note that `5` is the exact offset of the callq immediate address in `main` (not particularly important how this is encoded, it might vary across different platforms or even inside one platform).

Anyway, given the external declaration of `func` you placed in C code, the compiler knows that it might not have yet a proper address for the function to place into callq.

When linker links together different object files, it makes sure that all such dangling addresses are successfully resolved.

Now answering your particular question - the key to matching relocation table entries (external declarations) to actual symbols (function or variable definitions) are their signatures. A particular signature produces such relocation entries and symbols, that might be matched. Different signatures are essentially different in terms of linkage.

Beyond this point, your question is actually quite broad. So please either ask for further research directions or make it more clear.

**EDIT:** please also note that I obtained these listings under x86_64 linux, you might get different results in your environment, but the idea will still be the same.

Comment: I understand how it happens. I just confuse for two fields in readelf -r Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000000a  000b00000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 fun - 4                                                             I know that info is symbol table entery for function but how this entry is mapped and why sym.value is 0000000 ??